# How to use military time to compute time interval

Tags: r, time

I'm using R and am trying to compute the number of hours someone slept. Currently, the bed time and wake times are reported in military time, so when I use difftime(), the interval between sleeping at 9pm (21:00) and waking up at 7AM (07:00) ends up being 14 hours, instead of 10 hours. Can someone help me figure out what I need to do so that it gives me the correct time difference?

Example data:

```
              bedtime                   waketime
1             1899-12-31 01:00:00       1899-12-31 06:00:00
2             1899-12-31 21:00:00       1899-12-31 07:00:00
3             1899-12-31 22:00:00       1899-12-31 06:00:00
```

Script used:

```
difftime(PSQI$wakeup_3, PSQI$bedtime_1, units = "hours")
 [1]   5.00 -14.00 -16.00
```

When what I would am looking for is

```
[1]   5.00  10.00  8.00
```

Thank you to anyone who can help!

Comment: The issue isn't the 24 hour time, it's that the `waketime`s for certain cases should be the next day, not earlier in the same day.

Comment: Thanks, @thelatemail, that makes sense. Do you by chance know how to indicate that it's the next time in R?

Comment: You can add 24*3600, (the number of seconds in a day) onto wake time and then use `difftime`

Comment: @Dave2e - that won't work for the first row because then they'll be sleeping for 29 hours.

Comment: @Dave2e, thanks for the idea! Realized what thelatemail has said too though. So close!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining the comments above from @thelatemail and @Dave2e, we can do

```
with(df, ifelse(bedtime > waketime, waketime + 86400 - bedtime, waketime - bedtime))
#[1]  5 10  8
```

We add 86400 seconds (1 day) only if `bedtime > waketime` and then take the difference. Make sure columns `bedtime` and `waketime` are actual `POSIXct` class.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(bedtime = structure(c(-2209096006, -2209024006, 
-2209020406), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), waketime = 
structure(c(-2209078006, 
-2209074406, -2209078006), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = 
"")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```